# How to paginate stripe concurrently?

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, pagination, stripe-payments

Stripe api [supports cursor-based pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#pagination). To retreive next page one should get id of last item in previous page.

Are there a way to retrieve pages concurrently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution here is to parallelize your requests based on the object's creation date and not just on the object id.

The first thread would start at the top of the list and continue to paginate until a certain date such as next month's first day. The second thread would do the same but with `created[lte]` set to that month's first day at 12 am. The third thread would do the same for the following month's first day, etc.